# c++: what is correct way of instantiate a class in stack

Tags: c++, class, object

```
class A{...};

  int main(){

   A a; //step 1

   A a();//step 2

  }
```

meanwhile i tried above  2 cases 
In the step 1 constructor is called 
In step 2 constructor is not called.

which one is valid .
It is pretty basic but pls explain either step 1 or step 2 is good for allocation in stack.

Comment: step 2 declares a function with no argument returning a A object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See C++ FAQ [Is there any difference between List x; and List x();?](http://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/ctors#empty-parens-in-object-decl)